# flutter problem of connection with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, flutter, nosql

im trying to connect with mongodb using mongodb packages but i have this problem [image]

my function is simple 
[image]

also im trying to connect with port 27017 but every hot restart i get a random port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just open 27017 in firwall and it will work